Locust Gevent friendly socket
I have the following client listed below to send request to my server using a custom protobuf message. How do I make this gevent friendly so I can make connection in parallel. Right now it seems the connection are made one by one in serie and it takes really long to create for example 50 users even if I specify to create ramp up the users by 50 every second.
https://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching
import ssl
import struct
import sys
import time
import certifi
from client.kvgmprotobuf import PbUnion_pb2

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_socket()
import socket

class FleetSyncClient():
    CERTIFICATE = 'mycertificate.pem'

    def __init__(self, host):

        self.hostname = host
        self.ssock = None

                

    
    def connect_terminal(self):

        try:
            # Set up the SSL context
            context = ssl.create_default_context()
            context.check_hostname = False
            context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE   
            context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.CERTIFICATE)

            # Open the SSL socket to the server
            with socket.create_connection((self.hostname, 443)) as sock:
                try:
                    self.ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.hostname)
                    print(f"Connected to FarmCentre server: {self.hostname}")
                    return
                except ssl.CertificateError as e:
                    print("Certificate validation error:", e)
                    print("Please check the server certifcate")
                except ssl.SSLError as e:
                    print(f"Connection with server {self.hostname} failed: {e}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("An error occurred:", e)
        except Exception as err:
            print(f"Connection with server {self.hostname} failed unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print("Failed to connect to DAS server")
        sys.exit(1)

    
    def disconnect_terminal(self):
        if self.ssock is not None:
            try:
                self.ssock.close()
            except Exception as err:
                print(f"Close connection failed{err=}, {type(err)=}")
                sys.exit(1)


    def abort(self, text):
        print(f"###Error: {text}")
        self.disconnect_terminal()
        sys.exit(1)




    def _send_message(self, data):
        try:
            # add data length 4 bytes MSB first
            data = struct.pack('<I', len(data)) + data
            # add two currently not used bytes
            data = b'\x00\x00' + data
            # add total length 4 bytes MSB first
            data = struct.pack('<I', len(data)) + data
            # print(binascii.hexlify(data))
            ####print(f"Sending {len(data)} bytes")
            self.ssock.sendall(data)
        except socket.error as e:
            self.abort(f"Error sending data: {e}")
        try:
            # receive the response
            self.ssock.settimeout(30)
            header_bytes = self.ssock.recv(10)
            # kvgmprotobuf message length is the last 4 bytes of the header
            protobuf_msg_len = struct.unpack('<I', header_bytes[-4:])[0]
            protobuf_response = b""
            while len(protobuf_response) < protobuf_msg_len:
                chunk = self.ssock.recv(1024)
                protobuf_response += chunk
            # print(f"Protobuf message: {binascii.hexlify(protobuf_response)}")
            ####print(f"Server response: {len(protobuf_response)} protobuf bytes")
            return protobuf_response
        except socket.error as e:
            self.abort(f"Error receiving response: {e}")

    # send kvgmprotobuf message to the server and return the server response kvgmprotobuf message
    def send_protobuf_message(self, message):
        ####Logger.debug(f"sent message:\n{message}")
        response_data = self._send_message(message.SerializeToString())
        # parse the serialized response bytes to a kvgmprotobuf message
        response_msg = PbUnion_pb2.PbUnion()
        response_msg.ParseFromString(response_data)
        ####print(f"{response_msg}")
        return response_msg


You should always apply gevent's monkey patch as early as possible, and you need to apply it to more than just socket (unless you have a good reason not to, then use patch_all())
If you do import locust at the very top, it will patch everything for you (so you should then remove your own patching)
There's also an example using gRPC here: https://github.com/locustio/locust/tree/master/examples/grpc (I realize you aren't really using gRPC, but there might be something good in there for you anyway)
Also (and maybe you're doing this somewhere else in your code), to get concurrency you must also spawn separate greenlets. Maybe this is a good place to start: https://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/

How do I use gevent.joinall in locust? If I use gevent.spawn it is never executed because I don't call gevent.joinall but the locustfile is handled behind the scenes for me. I use the on_start method in my locust file to call my connect_terminal function

Sorry, I dont understand exactly what you're doing. But in general you dont need to do join to let other greenlets run, you just need to sleep (or do some io). Here's an example of how to spawn a greenlet and wait for events in a locust user: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/users/socketio.py
